# Devo adotar o padrão de nomenclatura do meu framework ou legado da equipe?

Tags: banco-de-dados, tabela-banco-de-dados

Aqui na empresa, todos seguem um padrão nos projetos:

> Todas as tabelas devem ser nomeadas no singular. Exemplos: "usuario", "evento", "categoria".

E também:

> A primary key principal é nomeada assim: "nome_da_tabela_id". Exemplos: "usuario_id", "evento_id". As demais colunas devem ser nomeadas com as três primeiras letras do nome da tabela, e o nome do campo. Exemplo: "usu_nome", "usu_endereco".

Acontece que vamos adotar o uso de frameworks como Laravel e CakePHP nos sistemas, e eles têm uma nomenclatura default para nomes de tabelas e colunas que eu queria aproveitar.

### Pergunta

Vale a pena seguir desta forma, e inserir o nome das tabelas manualmente nas classes dos frameworks, ou estas não são boas práticas? Quais são as boas práticas, com base nos **exemplos de literatura** e **estudos de caso**?

Este banco de dados será modelado para um novo sistema, não dependendo assim de compatibilidade com outros sistemas.

Comment: Estou levando esta discussão para o meta: http://meta.br.stackoverflow.com/questions/482 @BetaSystems-RodrigoDuarte

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Se um determinado framework tem um padrão, seguir este padrão sempre vai te dar menos trabalho do que ficar adaptando ele a alguma realidade.

No seu caso, se o Laravel e CakePHP possuem um formato de nomeclatura para tabelas e colunas, alterar este padrão para algo customizado seu vai gerar um trabalho extra (toda vez que você for utilizar algo automático do framework, terá que lembrar de ir configurar alguma coisa manualmente). E isto é uma fonte potencial de bugs.

Se a norma da sua empresa for mesmo inflexível, ou justificada por algum outro motivo (ex.: quantidade de código legado, reuso das tabelas/colunas em outros códigos), você então não terá escolha, mas deixe registrado esta alteração do default do framework.

Answer (score 4):

Olha,

Eu sigo "as boas práticas" da Microsoft:

**Tabelas**

1. Pluralizadas
2. Primeira letra maiúsculas para cada palavra (CamelCase)
3. Sem `_` ou qualquer outro símbolo

**Campos**

1. Nome da tabela somado à palavra "Id" (ex.: TabelaId)
2. Primeira letra maiúscula para cada palavra (CamelCase)

Essas são as práticas que eu uso, sendo boas ou não, pra mim facilita muito e fica bem legível tudo, código, base e afins.

[Este é um manual da Microsoft](https://www.google.com.br/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CDgQFjAB&url=http://download.microsoft.com/download/d/9/4/d948f981-926e-40fa-a026-5bfcf076d9b9/BPSemanticDBModeling.docx&ei=2MLWUpnQIavNsQSqkoKQDw&usg=AFQjCNFUGjaCXmzfm8q8GMymQwqqZmqkKA&sig2=RHTpo7L7V0GrLgmVGGbjAQ&bvm=bv.59378465,d.cWc&cad=rja), onde está boa parte do que eu falei e muito mais. Nesse manual, eles tiraram a pluralização.

Outra coisa, sobre o que você disse dos frameworks, Laravel e CakePHP, e eu esqueci de comentar é que é mais fácil você seguir o padrão do que alterá-lo, mas se a empresa pede, ou você acha que o padrão deles torna difícil a leitura do projeto/banco, é melhor você adotar outro padrão, o que melhor convier para você ou sua empresa.

---

Outro artigo interessante: http://architects.dzone.com/articles/20-database-design-best

Comment: Você tem alguma referencia para esse material?

Comment: Cara, em mãos não, mas vou procurar e atualizo aqui.

Comment: Acho que sei por que eles tiraram a pluralização... Isso dá uma mão-de-obra danada, e quando entra localização no meio a coisa fica pior ainda. Lembro do Ruby on Rails (que usa [CoC](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conven%C3%A7%C3%A3o_sobre_configura%C3%A7%C3%A3o)), havia um bug no método de pluralização, e eles tiveram que **manter o bug** porque consertá-lo ia quebrar vários códigos legados! Vou te falar, o principal motivo pelo qual nunca me aproximei demais do RoR foi essa convenção - e sua inflexibilidade para contornar.

Comment: Então, no .NET, quem usa essa pluralização, por default, é o Entity Framework, se você fizer por CodeFirst e não setar como false a opção da pluralização, ele vai criar todas as tabelas com pluralização, claro que funciona perfeitamente em inglês; mas não consigo enxergar muitos problemas com o SQL e .NET, mas entendo o ponto que você abordou.